# AngularJS not showing ng-repeat, just showing an empty list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem trying to show a collection of objects in AngularJS.

The ng-repeat is just showing the items but with empty data in console. I get the JSON data properly, catching the scope items with success of my api. 
In my view it's just showing a gray bar at the bottom, the data is printing on bottom but not on ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-controller="userController">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2>Users</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="user">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <input ng-model="user.name" type="text" placeholder="User Name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input ng-model="user.email" type="email" placeholder="User Email " class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" placeholder="Set Your Password" class="form-control" >

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select ng-model="user.admin" name="" id="" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Admin</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button ng-click="createUser(user)" class="btn btn-success">Create User</button>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3>All Users</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>id</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Options</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                                <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{users}}
```

Please, see 
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cLyW.png) and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nngO8.png).

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
angular
    .module('anicasioApp')
    .controller('userController', userController);
    function userController($scope, $http){
        $scope.createUser = createUser;
        $scope.users = [];

    function init(){
        getAllUsers();
    }
    init();

    function getAllUsers() {

        $http.get('/api/userpost/')
        .then(function(users) {
            $scope.users = users;
            console.log($scope.users);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            err.sendStatus(400);
        })
    }

    function createUser(users) {
        console.log(users);
        $http.post('/api/userpost/', users)
            .then(getAllUsers);
            console.log(users);
    }

    }
})();

    // Users Model
function getAllUsers(req, res) {
    UserModel
        .find()
        .then(function(users) {
            res.json(users);
        }), 
        function(err){
            res.sendStatus(400);
        }
}
```

Comment: Could you, please, post your html code?

Comment: I posted above Asiel Leal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you initialize *$scope.users* as empty array *[]*, but in you $http promise you assign in response, which is data. So, try to change this assignment to `$scope.users = users.data;`

```
$http.get('/api/userpost/').then(function(users) {
  $scope.users = users.data;
  console.log($scope.users);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(error);
  // sendStatus() function belongs to express on the serverside
  // err.sendStatus(400);
})
```

now in your HTML you should be able to iterate over it:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users track by user._id">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Andriy works properly now can get data on my view your awesome  thanks to all for quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

@Andriy is right...

In your function

```
function getAllUsers() {

    $http.get('/api/userpost/')
    .then(function(users) { // var 'users' is actually your server 'response'
        $scope.users = users;
        console.log($scope.users);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        err.sendStatus(400);
    })
}
```

you shouldn't do this `$scope.users = users;`, but this: `$scope.users = users.data;` because the difference between the two different ways we can handle promises:

When you use

```
$http.get('/myserviceurl').
    success(data){//mycode}
```

you are getting `response.data` the standar parameter returned by the server...
but if you do (this is how you are doing it!)

```
$http.get('/myserviceurl').
    then(response){//mycode}
```

... what you are getting is `response` from server, which contains the `data` variable which carries the data you want.